# Docker alpine:edge how to enable testing

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

EDIT: now Alpine may provide a bazel package...
ref: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=bazel*&

I want to install [*bazel*](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/bazel) from testing repository in my Dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:edge AS env
RUN apk add --no-cache git build-base bazel
CMD [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

observed:

```bash
$ docker build --target env -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:edge AS env
 ---> 24cae4d038c0
Step 2/3 : RUN apk add --no-cache git build-base bazel
 ---> Running in 6ce08db21af0
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  bazel (missing):
    required by: world[bazel]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache git build-base bazel' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
# Create a virtual environment with all tools installed
# ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine
FROM alpine:edge AS env
RUN apk add --no-cache git build-base
RUN apk add --no-cache -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing bazel
CMD [ "/bin/sh" ]
```